# How to make hg ignore filter case insensitive

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, hgignore

I am trying to set up an hg repo for an old project on Windows. I want to ignore images, binaries, and some 3rd party source files, however these files contains different casing for the same patterns, for example, .jpg and .JPG, abc_sth and ABC_sth.

I learned that hgignore is case sensitive, do I have to list the different cases all in the hgignore file, or are there options that I can turn on to make the ignore filter case insensitive?

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer so that people know that the question had been answered.

Comment: I want to do so but I don't have enough rep to answer my own question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally I get enough rep to post my own answer.

Use regex syntax, and prefix `(?i)`. So the pattern for the example I used here can be

```
syntax: regexp
(?i)\.jpg
(?i)abc_
```